# How to show product detail from productId in cart table in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have 2 tables:

- Table `Cart`: `Id, ProductId, Qty`
- Table `Product`: `Id, Name, Stock, Desc`

And this view model:

```
public class Cart
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product product { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Stock{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Desc{ get; set; }
}
```

I have cart service

```
public List<Cart> GetCart(int id)
{
     var data = _context.Carts.Where(c => c.AccountId == id).ToList();
     return data;
}
```

and to show it in frontend i have

```
public async Task Index()

{
     int id = (int)HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("AccountId");
     var data = _cart.GetCart(id);
     return View(data);
}
```

and in front end, i want to show all cart items of this account id, but it have an error

```
@model List<Web.Data.Entities.Cart>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<p class="h6">@item.product.Price</p>
<p class="h6">@item.product.Desc</p>
}
```

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.**

I try, but I don't know how to show `Product` detail when selecting all data from Cart? Help me, please

Comment: Hello have you tried the solution provided? Is there anything else that I can help you on this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to show Product detail when selecting all data from Cart?

Based on your class defination within your cart class you have productId, all you need to do is, you would fetch product from your product list based on your cart productId.

You could use linq [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0) or [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-8.0) in order to sort product collcetion as per your cart item.

Let's have a look in practice,

Product List:

Assuming, you have following product list:

```cs
var productList = new List<ProductTable>()
            {
                new ProductTable(){ Id =101,Name = "Pro-A",Stock = 50, Desc = "Product Desc A"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =102,Name = "Pro-B",Stock = 100,Desc = "Product Desc B"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =103,Name = "Pro-C",Stock = 130,Desc = "Product Desc C"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =104,Name = "Pro-D",Stock = 200,Desc = "Product Desc D"},


            };
```

Cart Item:

```cs
var cartList = new List<Cart>()
            {
                new Cart(){ Id =1,Quantity = 5, ProductId = 101},
                new Cart(){ Id =2,Quantity = 2, ProductId = 104}
            };
```

Get cart item with product details:

```cs
public ActionResult GetProductDetailsFromProductIdInCart()
        {
            var productList = new List<ProductTable>()
            {
                new ProductTable(){ Id =101,Name = "Pro-A",Stock = 50, Desc = "Product Desc A"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =102,Name = "Pro-B",Stock = 100,Desc = "Product Desc B"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =103,Name = "Pro-C",Stock = 130,Desc = "Product Desc C"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =104,Name = "Pro-D",Stock = 200,Desc = "Product Desc D"},


            };
            var cartList = new List<Cart>()
            {
                new Cart(){ Id =1,Quantity = 5, ProductId = 101, ProductTable = productList.Where(p=>p.Id == 101).FirstOrDefault()},
                new Cart(){ Id =2,Quantity = 2, ProductId = 104, ProductTable = productList.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == 104)},
               


            };

            return Ok(cartList);
        }
```

**Note:** I am executing query on demo product list, in your project you would execute it on your product dbContext having the productId from your cart item.

[image]

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can learn more details about [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) from [this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

**Update:**

> I want to show all cart items of this account id, but it have an error

As you have updated th question; thus, here is the updated solution you could implement. I haven't found anything by accountId within your model, therefore, searching by CartId, as per your class Id.

Cart Service:

```cs
public List<Cart> GetCart(int? Id)
        {
            var productList = new List<ProductTable>()
            {
                new ProductTable(){ Id =101,Name = "Pro-A",Stock = 50, Desc = "Product Desc A"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =102,Name = "Pro-B",Stock = 100,Desc = "Product Desc B"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =103,Name = "Pro-C",Stock = 130,Desc = "Product Desc C"},
                new ProductTable(){ Id =104,Name = "Pro-D",Stock = 200,Desc = "Product Desc D"},


            };
            var cartList = new List<Cart>()
            {
                new Cart(){ Id =1,Quantity = 5, ProductId = 101, ProductTable = productList.Where(p=>p.Id == 101).FirstOrDefault()},
                new Cart(){ Id =1,Quantity = 2, ProductId = 104, ProductTable = productList.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == 104)},
                new Cart(){ Id =2,Quantity = 10, ProductId = 102, ProductTable = productList.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == 102)},
                new Cart(){ Id =2,Quantity = 52, ProductId = 103, ProductTable = productList.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == 103)},
                new Cart(){ Id =3,Quantity = 10, ProductId = 104, ProductTable = productList.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Id == 104)},


            };
            return cartList.Where(cid=>cid.Id == Id).ToList();
        }
```

**Note:** Searching cart by Id as a cart may have many product.

Cart Index:

```cs
public IActionResult IndexCart(int? cartId)
        {  
            var data = GetCart(cartId);
            return View(data);
        }
```

**Note:** For demo, I am directly passing cartId in your scenario, you would get it from session.

View:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<YourProjectName.ModelsFoldre.Cart>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                CartId
            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity
            </th>
            <th>
                Product Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Product Desc
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductTable!.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductTable!.Desc)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

[image]